# How to compact the VBA-project in an Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm am searching for a way to compact the VBA project in an Excel workbook.
I recently discovered that the VBA project in one of my workbooks had grown over 60 Mb when I opened the workbook with WinZip.
The compressed workbook (.xlsm) exceeded the 10Mb limit that my email provider has set for email attachments. I had to take action or find another way to distribute.

I was able to reduce the size from more than 10Mb to less than 2Mb but that was a lot of work and I'm not certain if we can automate this.

This is the procedure I followed:

- Export the code behind all sheets, ThisWorkbook, Forms, CodeModules and ClassModules.
- Save the workbook as .xlsx (All code is removed)
- Reopen the workbook and save as .xlsm
- Import all modules again and past the code behind the sheets.

Now that I know that the VBA project grows without an option in Excel to compact it with a single press of a button, at least not an option that I know of. I would like to create some tool to do this every time I am to distribute the file.

Any ideas how the do this?

Comment: Use Codecleaner: http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm

Comment: Have you thought about uploading your file to the cloud?

Comment: Look at saving it as a binary file (`xlsb`) instead of an `xlsx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had good experiences with this tool:

[VBA Decompiler](http://orlando.mvps.org/VBADecompilerMore.asp)